# Can I import a module's export into an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have some imports that look like this

```
import {foo as xFoo, bar as xBar} from "widgetX"
import {foo as yFoo, bar as yBar} from "widgetY"
```

I don't want to import everything for each module, but I want to avoid the prefixing to distinguish which `foo` and `bar` I am using.

Maybe this is just a silly hangup, but I'd much rather say `x.foo` or `y.bar`.  Of course, I could map it after, but that would leave `xFoo` and the others lying around and is too much for this nitpick of an issue.

**EDIT**

This is a more meaningful example...

```
import xFoo from "widgetX/foo"
import xBar from "widgetX/bar"
import yFoo from "widgetY/foo"
import yBar from "widgetY/bar"
```

Comment: You can use `import * as x from 'package'`

Comment: @kennarddh yes, but that would import everything, not just the parts I need

Comment: @drs9222 The entire JavaScript file is evaluated nonetheless, so you do not save in performance or bandwidth by importing only some parts.

Comment: @Domino good point
I combined a couple of discussions I had with my team and over-simplified things.
I edit my question to give a better example where performance does matter